# Steam API. Вывод инвентаря человека

Tags: php, веб-программирование, steam-web-api, steam

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании кода.
Выскакивает вот эта ошибка:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd4/315/2689315/public_html/inventory.php on line 6

Хотел, чтобы при заходе на страницу показывался инвентарь человека.

```php
<?php
   require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
$get_content = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/id/".$steamprofile['steamid']."/inventory/json/570/2");
$data_image = (array) json_decode($get_content) -> rgInventory;
$count_content = count($data_image);
$data_content = (array) json_decode($get_content, TRUE);
echo "Total items: $count_content <br><br>";
for ($i=0; $i<$count_content; $i++) {
    $element_name = array_shift($data_content[rgInventory]);
    $name_item = "$element_name[classid]_$element_name[instanceid]";
    echo "<img src='http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/";
    print_r($data_content['rgDescriptions'][$name_item]['icon_url']);
    echo "' style='width:90px; height:90px; float:left; margin: 5px; outline: 1px solid black;'>";
    getInventory($steamapi, $steamid, $userid);
}
?>
```

Comment: Сразу говорю, код не мой. Разбираюсь в php на уровне новичка, но сам код более-менее понятен. :P

Comment: Добавте код из картинки как текст. Картинку можете удалить.

Comment: Я не знаю, как быстро ответить так, чтобы вам не пришлось поиграться с кодом... Легкое предупреждение Notice - это не ошибка, в вашем случае "Trying to get property of non-object" значит, что к переменной обращаются как к объекту, но это не объект (скорее всего, простой массив, но может быть и другое). Посмотрите, что у вас на 6-й строке, и выведите это с помощью var_dump(), чтобы узнать, что же это, если не объект.

Comment: @therainycat
Как вы и говорили вывел `$data_image` с помощью `var_dump();`.Получился массив `array(0) { }`. Как сделать так, чтобы обращение _обьекта_ было через _массив_?.

Comment: `(array) json_decode($get_content) -> rgInventory;` декодируешь в объект, затем пытаешься привести его к массиву и потом обращаешься как к объекту. либо `json_decode(.., true)` и потом работать как с массивом, либо просто убрать `(array)` слева и продолжать работать как с объектом.

Answer (score 1):

Если сделать так:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/id/".$steamprofile['steamid']."/inventory/json/570/2");
$data = json_decode($content, true);
$items = $data['rgInventory'];
```

То в `$items` будет храниться массив с `id`, `classid`, `instanceid`, `amount`, `pos`.

Если вы хотите вывести инвентарь в человекопонятном виде, то вам нужно получить больше данных(название, картинку и тд.)

Все эти данные будут в $data['rgDescriptions'], ключом к массива этих данных является строку `$classid . '_' . $instanceid`, где `$classid` и `$instanceid` это элементы из `$data['rgInventory']`